# USB thumb drive misbehaving on one PC - 100% load indicated, and files on it are barely accessible

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I have a problem with one specific PC and one specific USB flash drive. The drive works on other computers, and I have other USB flash sticks (different models) that work on this PC.

The problem looks like this and starts a second or two after plugging the drive in:

[image]

As you can see, it didn't even receive a drive letter this time. Sometimes it does, and you can browse this drive and access files, but it's super slow.

I have never faced such a problem and don't know where to start. I did try deleting the driver for this device completely, but this didn't help.

Sometimes it's working normally for more than 2 seconds - say, for 15 seconds, but then the 100% load starts again and it's unresponsive again.

An interesting fact is that I also have a different hard drive with a different Windows 10 installation that I also used in this PC, and there was no such problem with that OS on the same hardware.

The OS is Windows 10 2004. I cannot update it at this time due to very restricted Internet access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible the drive had been physically removed *from that PC*, leaving erroneous information on the PC. If the USB drive appears to be perfectly OK on other PC's, then first try is to remove any remnants of previous connection from the Registry. However, rather than directly modifying the Registry with Regedit, it's safer to use a third-party tool such as Nirsoft's free [USBDeview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) .

[image: Remove USB]

In the example above, with the USB stick *not* plugged in,

- Run *USBDeview* as Administrator.
- Search for the device. If you cannot easily find it, plug it in, refresh the view in *USBDeview*, sort on *Connected*, and note the change when you remove the device and refresh the list. The *Refresh* button has green circling arrows.
- Disconnect the problematic USB device.
- Uninstall that device... the next time it is plugged in, it will make a new entry.

If that does *not* fix the issue, then you might want to examine the device in a disk editing tool, such Windows *diskmgmt.msc*. BTW, the write speed shown, **4.1 KB/s**, is incredibly slow, perhaps indicating an outside issue: look for some process, e.g., malware, continually trying to write to it.

Please let us know if this helps.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I didn't know about USBDeview. Unfortunately, following your advice didn't help. Any tips on how I can find which process causes the load when the drive doesn't receive a letter, which is most of the time?

Comment: P. S. I think it did help! The activity continued for maybe 30 seconds after I followed your advice and then ceased. There is no such activity on subsequent re-insertions. Before that I tried waiting for minutes and the activity didn't change.

Comment: Glad it worked. It's interesting that Windows keeps a ;list of all USB devices ever connected, yet quickly generates a new one if an item is removed.

Comment: It is very interesting, I would be curious to learn what exactly it is for and what's the benefit of caching this info (weighed against the bugs when it becomes stale for some reason). Thank you very much for help!